# Ansible added flathub repo isn't recognized

Tags: ansible, flatpak

I'm using Ansible to setup my linux machines (Fedora) at home. I'm using the following to add flathub repo as part of role:

```yaml
- name: Enable flatpak repository.
  tags: repository,flatpak
  community.general.flatpak_remote:
    name: flathub
    flatpakrepo_url: "https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo"
    method: system
    state: present
```

and then for example:

```yaml
- name: Install VLC media player.
  tags: software,vlc
  community.general.flatpak:
    name: org.videolan.VLC
    state: present
```

Then ansible throws an error that VLC was not found.

When I use `flatpak remotes` it shows:

| Name | Options |
| --- | --- |
| fedora | system,oci |
| flathub | system,**filtered** |

I have to use manually `flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo` and then remotes shows just system for flathub. After that adding VLC using Ansible works like charm.

Am I doing something wrong in he playbook / role?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the **filtered** part of your flathub remotes options. I'm guessing you did this on a version of Fedora < 38. Try issuing the following command:

```
flatpak remote-modify flathub --no-filter
```

Then vlc (and everything else) should be found as expected. Fedora Linux prior to 38 FILTERED what was available on flathub, see [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Filtered_Flathub_Applications) for details

Comment: Sorry didn't seen your answer as it didn't send me an email (I have to have a look into the account preferences). Yes I did that on Fedora < 38, but the question was why it is adding filtered flathub repo? The "package" used by the playbook is just adding repo.

Anyway, I know that from F38 there were some changes regarding flathub. Didn't have time to test playbook on new version, yet.